# How make RestSharp request like a browser request?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

Surprisingly I noticed that the page that is obliged to share public API (https://danepubliczne.imgw.pl/api/data/hydro/), seems to block the RestSharp request but at the same time URL at the browser return results more or less correctly... There is no one pattern of how request is blocked and I don't know if for sure that is intentional. Still, quite often  Restharp requests are unsuccessful. The request ends with a timeout or one of 500s errors. At the same time, the request for the chrome browser works in most cases correctly. Below is the code that is used to get a response from that service

```
RestClient client;
RestRequest request;
client = new RestClient("https://danepubliczne.imgw.pl/api/data/hydro/");
request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
response = client.Execute(request);
```

So could you recommend to me how to make a Restsharp request looks like a request from example the last version of the chrome browser?

Comment: Can you share a [mre]? What status code do you get as a response? Are you setting a User-Agent?

Comment: no, i' not setting User-Agent that I think can help. when it comes to error there is no one pattern, sometimes that is timeout, sometimes 502 and sometimes incorrect response is returned (html instead of json)

Comment: @gunr2171 I edited question and added missing informations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add headers to your request. It seems that at least `User-Agent` is required. Try something like this:

```cs
var request = new RestRequest(...);
...
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36");
```